# Push Notifications: error occurred while loading the keystore: invalid null input

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5, appery.io

[Appery.io] Ionic application doesn't receive Push Notifications. I send it using Appery.io tool, but I everytime see the error in the tab History and Schedule: *error occurred while loading the keystore: invalid null input*.
Has anybody dealt with this before?

Answer (score 2):

It happens if you use the wrong Push Notification certificate or the wrong password of that certificate. Please generate a new one and build the app again, it should work well